# sending data from excel to ASP.NET MVC web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, vba, entity-framework

Why am I not receiving the response text from ASP.NET web service?

Hers is my vba code to sending data to web service:

```
Sub SendData()
  Dim HttpReq As New WinHttp.WinHttpRequest

  HttpReq.Open "POST", "http://localhost:11121/Student/Insert/", False

  HttpReq.Send "id=jsmith112"

  MsgBox HttpReq.ResponseText  
End Sub
```

Here is My code to print the data in my view:

```
Response.Write("Student ID = " + Request.Form["id"]);
```

I just see "Student ID = " in the MsgBox and not the student id with it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you show you Asp.net mvc service code? might help

Comment: Argh my eyes - they are bleeding! I suggest you use parantheses to make things more readable in your functions. Just a recommendation though.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry not sure but what i'll do first is check the `Status` or `StatusText` property.
Please be sure about the content type:

```
objXmlHttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

You can debug your service, too, to look at the headers you are receiving and, of course, validate you are receiving the request properly. :)

good luck!